# How do I get full resolution?

Tags: drivers, resolution

I know this has been asked before, but I've tried nearly every solution I could find.

When I run Additional Drivers, it doesn't come up with anything. After installing my graphics cards drivers via sudo apt-get, the highest resolution I can attain is still 1024x768 (I want 1920x1080).

I have tried to edit xorg.conf to no avail, but I have a strong feeling I'm messing something up.

I do not know what is up with it. When it I ran lspci -v, this is what I got:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 11c0 (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 2660
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia_current, nvidia_current_updates, nouveau, nvidiafb
```

It says access has been denied regarding its capabilities. What does that mean? Is it even significant?

I'm new to Linux and just moved over from windows, and am still getting used to the new file types and use of the Terminal and what not. Thanks for any help given! (Sorry for being such a newbie!)

Link to the requested [pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5630972/) of the sudo lshw.

Okay, it's fixed now. At full resolution. After going through the terminal and downloading and updating I think x-swat, and then restarting, it fixed it. Thanks for the help and friendliness, guys.

Comment: 1. Don't ever apologize for being a newbie. We've all been there, and therefore shouldn't look down upon it.

Comment: 2. Could you run `sudo lshw` in a terminal and paste the results at the ubuntu pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Pastebin link is now in the original post, and thanks for helping me.

Comment: `<access denied>` means the user you dont not have the permission to view it, run `sudo lapci -v` to get the denied info; what does this give you? `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer string"` you may need to install [glxinfo](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/glxinfo)

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about the solution which worked for me, [here](http://dfourtheye.blogspot.in/2013/04/ubuntu-screen-custom-resolution.html)

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VBOX0 "1600x900_60.00"
sudo xrandr --output VBOX0 --mode "1600x900_60.00"
```

1. First command creates a new mode with resolution 1600x900
2. Second command makes it available for use, with display (in this case VBOX0)
3. Third command selects the newly added mode as the display resolution for the specified display

**To change this to any custom resolution,** just replace 1600 with the width you want and 900 with the height you want.